# Solving linear regression minimizing quadratic cost

Tags: python, optimization, cvxpy, convex-optimization

I want to solve linear regression in the following way

[image]

When I try with minimizing the sum of cost it works fine,

```
import cvxpy as cp
import numpy as np

n = 5
np.random.seed(1)
x = np.linspace(0, 20, n)
y = np.random.rand(x.shape[0])
theta = cp.Variable(2)


# This way it works
objective = cp.Minimize(cp.sum_squares(theta[0]*x + theta[1] - y))
prob = cp.Problem(objective)
result = prob.solve()
print(theta.value)
```

I want to try minimizing the quadratic cost as follows:

```
#This way it does not work,
X = np.row_stack((np.ones_like(y), x)).T 
objective_function = (y - X*theta).T*(y-X*theta)
obj = cp.Minimize(objective_function)
prob = cp.Problem(obj)
result = prob.solve()
print(theta.value)
```

However, I get the following error:

```
  raise DCPError("Problem does not follow DCP rules. Specifically:\n" + append)
  cvxpy.error.DCPError: The problem does not follow DCP rules. Specifically:
```

Any idea why this happens?

Comment: I'm guessing that the multiplication in `X*theta` is working element-wise. Possibly may work if you do `@` instead?

Comment: Are you interested in finding the minimum or are you interested in finding the minimum in this specific way? Because there is a closed-form formula for this problem...

Comment: @chthonicdaemon still I get the same error

Comment: @RiccardoBucco yeap I want to find the minimum but not cp.sum_squares rather the way I tried.

Comment: @RiccardoBucco yep I know the close form solution, I want to know why I got that error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think CVXPY does not understand that both `y - X*theta` are the same in

```
  objective_function = (y - X*theta).T*(y-X*theta)
```

Is

```
  objective = cp.Minimize(cp.norm(y - X*theta)**2)
```

or

```
  objective = cp.Minimize(cp.norm(y - X*theta))
```

acceptable? (Both give the same solution)

Comment: If that's the case, it's totally fine, thank youuu